# Property [Total_Sayur] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, view

how to display or call value in array in laravel blade view ?

I already have the data that appears in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5fn6.jpg)

I still don't understand how to call the data in the :

```
<h3>@currency($laporan->Total_Sayur)</h3>
```

I'm tired of trying it in various ways and it always appears another error message. Please help me

**MyController**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::count();
    $kelompok = Kelompok::count();
    $anggota = Anggota::count();

    $laporan = Anggota::select('kecamatan', Produk::raw('avg(total_sayur) as Total_Sayur, avg(total_buah) as Total_Buah,avg(total_ikan) as Total_Ikan, avg(total_ternak) as Total_Ternak'))
        ->leftjoin('produk', 'produk.anggota_id', '=', 'anggota.id')
        ->where('kecamatan', '=', 'Ngajum')
        ->GroupBy('kecamatan')
        ->get();

    // return $laporan;

    return view('Dashboard.index', compact('users', 'kelompok', 'anggota', 'laporan'));
}
```

View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-info">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>@currency($laporan->Total_Sayur)</h3>

                <p>TOTAl KEMANFAATAN</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-pricetagg"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You’re utilising a collection, not a single instance so you need to iterate (loop) over $laporan using @foreach and access each element that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution start from here....

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">

        @foreach($laporan as $item)

            <!-- small box -->

            <div class="small-box bg-info">

                <div class="inner">

                    <h3>@currency($item->Total_Sayur)</h3>

                    <p>TOTAl KEMANFAATAN</p>

                </div>

                <div class="icon">

                    <i class="ion ion-pricetagg"></i>

                </div>

                <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>

            </div>

        @endforeach

    </div>

</div>
```